# Surface integral: Where am I making mistake?

Tags: surface-integrals

For the vector field $a = [-z,x-y,-2y+2z]^T$ and the area $F$ on the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = 9$ , which is above the ground plane $z = 0$ , in front of the plane $x = 0$ and between the cross plane $y = 0$ and lies to the their parallel plane $y = 5$ , calculate the following integral:

$\int_{F}^{} \! a\cdot dn \, = ?$

So I use that:

$x=3cos(u)$

$y=v$

$z=3sin(u)$

and than I calculate normal vector.

I get integral 
$\int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{\Pi/2}\begin{pmatrix}-z\\x-y\\-2y+2z\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}3sin(u)\\ 0\\ 3sin(u)\end{pmatrix}dudv $

$\int_{0}^{6}\int_{0}^{\Pi/2}\begin{pmatrix}-3sin(u)\\3cos(u)-v\\-2v+6sin(u)\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}3sin(u)\\ 0\\ 3sin(u)\end{pmatrix}dudv $

$\int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{\Pi/2}-9sin^2(u)-6vsin(u)+18sin^2(u)$

$\int_{0}^{\Pi/2}45sin^2(u)-75sin(u)du$

at the end I get that $45*\Pi/4-75$ which isn't correct result.

Solution is: $-195/2+45/2*\Pi$

Comment: are you sure your normal vector is correct?

Comment: The normal vector to a cylinder should be the same as the normal vector to a circle, namely, a scalar multiple of the position vector (in the plane).

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} -3sin(u)\\ 0\\ 3cos(u)\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ @JoshuaLin

Comment: How do you mean? @ted

Comment: So compute that cross product again, carefully! By the way, you didn't state in the problem how the surface is oriented. If the normal is pointing outward, your cross product (once you get it correct) is in the wrong direction.

Comment: How do you mean wrong direction?